# single call to multiprocessing.Process.start() spawning 100s of processes in Windows when running in PyDev

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pydev

I was trying to work on a component that uses the multiprocessing module in PyDev, but was having problems where running the code was spawning 100s of python processes in the OS and killing my machine.  I had my code call `run()` instead of `start()`, and it worked fine (except, of course, it was all single threaded since `start()` is what actually spawns the processes), so that suggests to me that my code was at least not doing anything insane like infinitely generating processes or something.  Further, I put together a little test code to see what was up:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def create_processes(num_processes, method, *args):

    processes = []
    for i in range(num_processes):
        processes.append(Process(target=method, args=args))
    return processes

def start_all(processes, stagger):

    for process in processes:
        process.start()
        if stagger:
            time.sleep(stagger)

processes = create_processes(2, time.sleep, 4)
start_all(processes, 0)
```

When I run this in the cli, it works fine; it spawns 2 new processes that end after the timeout.  However, when I run it in PyDev, it generates ~600 processes (or at least that's how many task manager shows before my machine becomes unresponsive).  I did a little debugging, and it seems to be blowing up in `Process.start()` on the line `self._popen = Popen(self)`.

I did a little searching around, but couldn't really find anything that seemed relevant.  Is the CLI automatically `join()`ing all `start()`ed processes to some separate manager to keep the reins on?  Do I need a thread in my code to `join()` all my processes to?  Is PyDev jacking around with things to try to maintain logging and control?  Is something else going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the starting point to the code, you should wrap the final two lines with `if __name__ == '__main__'` in order to prevent the subprocess from starting their own subprocesses:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = create_processes(2, time.sleep, 4)
    start_all(processes, 0)
```

Comment: Oh, I think I get it.  So what you are saying is that when I run from the file, when the spawned process imports the module to get at the method it is trying to call, it is re-executing the process creation code?  But what do the spawned children see as their `__name__`?

Comment: From the [python docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html): "Within a module, the module’s name (as a string) is available as the value of the global variable `__name__`." So if you module is named fido.py, `__name__` would just be `'fido'`. It's only when you execute modules as scripts that `__name__` is set to `'__main__'`.

Comment: Oh.  That makes lots of obvious sense now.  Can't believe I banged my head against this so long.... thanks.